# How to access counters from Reporting task in Nifi 1.2.0

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

IN Nifi 1.4.0, in order to access counters from a scripted reporting task, you can do something like:

```
context.eventAccess.controllerStatus.processGroupStatus.each { pg ->
    pg.processorStatus.each { ps ->
        ps.counters.each { counter
            System.out.println("${counter.key} -> ${counter.value})
    }
}
```

That's because ProcessorStatus API exposes:

```
Map<String,Long>    getCounters()
```

However, I'm with NiFi 1.2.0.

Which does not have this method for class ProcessorReportingTask.

I'm desperately searching for a way to access the counters from a ReportingTask (so, through a ReportingContext, because that's what's bound within the script).

Because my ReportingTask is reporting metrics to our graphite server.

Any Idea?

I know I could access the metrics through REST APIs.
But then I would vanish completely the goal of my ScriptedReporingTask, and I would need to setup an additional piece of software to collect these metrics from outside. While the ReponrtingTask will just run from NiFi system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will have to upgrade to 1.4.0 in order to get access to the getCounters method, there is no other way I know of through a ReportingContext which is why it was added in 1.4.0 as part of this JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-106

Comment: Bryan, Thanks a lot for pointing me to theJIRA.
indeed, you seem to be right, and the discussion seem to indicate that others have felt there was no other way already. Well... 1.4 will come (to us, I mean. We're currently bound to 1.2), soon. Accepting this answer.